# Difference between backticks and quotes in aes function in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Ok, this is kind of an odd one. I was answering a question for a beginner around `geom_histogram`, and the OP posted an example using backticks. He neglected to add data so I made it up, and then found an answer, not even noticing the backticks. But another (actually more elegant) answer was posted without backticks. It did not really work, but it worked a lot better with the backticks.

But now I am puzzled. I don't see why there should have been a difference at all. Even the ggplot list is almost identical, only the `ggplot$mapping` element is different as far as I can see (ok, that is a biggie). I have googled about, but I don't see what is going on.

So here is the code:

**This** (quotes around `Log Number` in `aes`):

```
#Generate some data
lon <- log(rnorm(1000, exp(6)))
state <- sample(c("c", "l", "t"), 1000, replace = T)
d <- data.frame(lon, state)
names(d) <- c("Log Number", "state")

# Plot it
gpsq <- ggplot(d, aes(x = 'Log Number', fill = state)) + geom_histogram()
print(gpsq)
```

yields **this**:

[image]

But **this** (backticks around `Log Number` in `aes`):

```
#Generate some data
lon <- log(rnorm(1000, exp(6)))
state <- sample(c("c", "l", "t"), 1000, replace = T)
d <- data.frame(lon, state)
names(d) <- c("Log Number", "state")

# Plot it
gpsq <- ggplot(d, aes(x = `Log Number`, fill = state)) + geom_histogram()
print(gpsq)
```

more correctly yields this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but this may provide some insight.  Try looking at the output of `aes(x = "lon", fill = state)` vs `aes(x = lon, fill = state)` vs `aes(x = \`lon\`, fill = state)`  With quotes, you wind up with a character, but with no quotes or backticks, you end up with a symbol.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Back ticks are the standard way of denoting a non-standard variable name in R. Quotes are used to indicate a string. Example:

```
`bad name` = 1
`bad name`
# [1] 1
```

This doesn't work with quotes.

```
"bad name" = 1
"bad name"
# [1] "bad name"
```

Generally, you shouldn't use these strange, non-standard names. But, if you ever have to, that's the way to do it. You *can* do pretty much anything,

```
`really-bad^name+violating*all()/[kinds] <- of == rules&!|` = 1
# works just fine
```

but that doesn't mean you *should*.

---

When it comes to `ggplot`, if you did

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = 1)) + geom_point()
```

you would expect that all the y-values would be 1. And you'd be right!

With a quoted string it's just the same:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = "mpg")) + geom_point()
```

except instead of a numeric as in the `y = 1` case above, you've given it a character - which is implicitly converted to a factor (with only one level) for a discrete y scale (with only one value). It doesn't matter if there's a column named `"mpg"` or not, because you've just passed `aes()` a value. `ggplot` doesn't look for a column named `mpg` like it doesn't look for a column named `1` in the first example.

With back ticks, you give `ggplot` something R recognizes as *an object name*, not just a value like `1` or `"some string"`. So `ggplot` *does* go looking for a column with that name.

```
# both of these work
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = `mpg`)) + geom_point()
```

---

While back ticks **do work**, and setting constants inside `aes()` usually does work, neither of these are very recommended. The preferred way to set constants is to **set constants outside `aes()`**. This is the only way to guarantee everything will work nicely in more complicated plots. Facets, in particular, often have errors or don't produce expected results if you try to do weird stuff inside `aes()` (especially transformations).

```
# better than above, set a constant outside of `aes()`
# Here I set y as a constant which is a bit unusual
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt)) + geom_point(y = 1)
# aesthetics that are more commonly set to constants are
# size, color, fill, etc.
```

For non-standard column names, `aes_string()` works well, and then it *expects* the aesthetic mappings to be quoted column names. This also is a good way to do things if you are writing a function that creates ggplots and needs to take column names as arguments.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = "wt", y = "mpg")) + geom_point()
# or, in a variable
my_y_column = "mpg"
ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = "wt", y = my_y_column)) + geom_point()
```

---

One more nice example, beginning to look under-the-hood, thanks to @TheTime:

Eventually, `ggplot` needs to evaluate everything, which will be done with `eval`. Consider the following:

```
a <- 1

eval(parse(text="a"))
# [1] 1

eval(parse(text='"a"'))
# [1] "a"

eval(parse(text="`a`"))
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you.

Comment: I just noticed It is also covered in Hadley's Advanced R book here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html - in the section "Binding names to values".